# Collapse bar as the user scrolls fragment (NestedScrollView)

Tags: java, android, xml

In my `ProfileFragment.java` I have a **collapsing toolbar** with the user banner and profile image. Inside that fragment too, I have a **NestedScrollView** (included in my XML) to make the collapsing toolbar collapse as the user is scrolling the fragment. Inside that **Nested ScrollView** I have a **RecyclerView**. What I want to achieve is, when the user is scrolling the RecyclerView, the collapsing toolbar collapses. I'm not achieving this and I don't know why.
This is the include I use in `ProfileFragment.java`

```
<include
    layout="@layout/content_scrolling_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="443dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="203dp" />
```

And this is the XML of that include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFotosPerfil"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="-150dp">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Why can't I get the effect of the bar collapsing has the user is scrolling the recyclerview and not the bar?

**EDIT**

This is just an example of what I want. Here, the full image is a **Collapsing Toolbar** and the text is a **NestedScrollView** with a TextView inside. As I scroll up the NestedScrollView, the toolbar becomes big again.

[image]

I want to do this but with the **Recycler View** inside my nested scrollview and, the collapsing toolbar of this dimensions. (I want to put it right after the collapsing toolbar)

[image]

This is my MAIN XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparabackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="203dp"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarDivider">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFotoCapa"
            android:layout_width="446dp"
            android:layout_height="203dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="-32dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/banner_profile"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picFotoPerfil3"
    android:layout_width="117dp"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-75dp"
    android:elevation="50dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparabackground"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/black" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLocalizacao2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="262dp"
    android:text="@string/LocalizacaoAtual"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteGrey"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparabackground"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right|center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.543"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picFotoPerfil3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.126"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtProfileTitulo3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="172dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/PerfilTitulo"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparabackground"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/picFotoPerfil3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNomeUtilizador2"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtLocalizacao2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/NomeUtilizador"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#323B45"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/picFotoPerfil3"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picFotoPerfil3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.042"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />






<include
    layout="@layout/content_scrolling_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="443dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="203dp" />
```

Comment: use setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) for your recyclerview

Comment: where is your `xml` for `AppBarLayout`?

Comment: @AbuYousuf Totally forgot, sorry, see my updated question please!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've accomplished it in my app -

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The key attribute here is the "layout_scrollFlags" which enables the Toolbar to collapse when scrolled down. Hope this helps.

EDIT - Have you included the `widget.Toolbar` inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`? The above layout code is what gives me the exact thing you're looking for.

Comment: You can also add a background to your toolbar by adding a drawable background attribute in your CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: I have that `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` in my collapsing toolbar. The problem is that it only scrolls when I scroll the collapsing toolbar and not when I scroll outside (in my NestedScrollView). What I want is to, when the users scrolls the NestedScrollView/RecyclerView, the tollbar collapses too, and, when the user scrolls back up the Nested/RecyclerView, the toolbar comes full again

Comment: Is your collapsingtoolbar a part of `content_scrolling_profile`? If it is, remove it out from that file and add it in the activity's main layout file. Don't include the toolbar in the `<include layout=...>` resource file.

Comment: No, that is part of my main file, not the include

Comment: I'm afraid that is not what I want because the toolbar keeps not scrolling when I'm scrolling my Nested ScrollView with the RecyclerView inside ahah Does the `<include>` need to be right after the toolbar?